# Apache Flink Stream-Stream Left Outer Join State

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I'm new to Apache Flink, and trying to understand the concepts using below scenario:

Let's say we have two streams of data that are being consumed from kafka topics: orders and transactions. For each order, we have one transaction - that confirms the order.

Subset of order data fields:
`{order_id: "unique", order_time: "timestamp"}`

Subset of transaction data fields:
`{transaction_id: "unique", orderId: "link to order", transaction_time: "timestamp"}`

Every day, we would like to get a count of all the orders that were placed (from the beginning of given day) - which don't have a linked transaction to it, these are our un-confirmed orders for today. Along with the counts, we would also like to get other stats like sum(order_qty * order_price) for unconfirmed orders at that instant along with list of all the un-confirmed orderid's

Ideally transactions happen within a few seconds of an order, but in some cases - if there is an issue with the processing system, the transactions would happen after (at most) 8 hours of the transaction.

My initial approach was to read these two streams, convert them to tables using Table API, and run a left outer join on their temporary view's. However, I have a few questions with this approach:

1. If we consume data from kafka, with event_time as watermarks - what would our `forBoundedOutOfOrderness` be? And in case an issue happens with the processing systems, how do we handle the 8 hour late data?
2. How do we let our LEFT OUTER JOIN create null records in real-time? Even if there is no data incoming on the transactions stream? I see idleness mentioned in a few posts, does that apply here?
3. If we run a query shown below, does this keep all the orders and transactions in state? or would it only keep the orders that have transaction_id as NULL?

```
    "SELECT *
    "FROM orders LEFT JOIN transactions",
    "ON orders.order_id = transactions.order_id",
    "WHERE transaction_id IS NULL"
```

4. Is this LEFT JOIN a correct approach to go forward, or if there is a better approach you would recommend?